# Low level built-in function to transpose expression (not array)

Tags: expression-manipulation, functional-style, built-in-symbols

I have an expression like this

```
F[G[1, b], G[3, y], G[4, y], G[5, u]]
```

that I would like to `Transpose` to obtain

```
G[F[1, 3, 4, 5], F[b, y, y, u]]
```

Since `Transpose` doesn't act on expressions (with heads different from `List`), what is the built-in function that makes this transformation?

I can do something like

```
G@@F@@@Transpose[F[G[1, b], G[3, y], G[4, y], G[5, u]] /. F|G->List]
```

but I'd rather use something lower level than that.

Comment: `Thread[F[G[1, b], G[3, y], G[4, y], G[5, u]], G]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread` does that:

```
Thread[F[G[1, b], G[3, y], G[4, y], G[5, u]], G]
```

> G[F[1, 3, 4, 5], F[b, y, y, u]]

Comment: Yep, that's it thanks!